# Set focus on autocomplete field

Tags: atk4

I have a form that has some fields.
One field is autocomplete
.
The field is filled with information from a table

```
$f->addField('autocomplete','idfield','Field')->setValueList( $this->api->db->dsql()  
 ->table('items')->field('id,name')->do_getAssoc() );
```

I'm trying to set the focus on that field when the page loads.

I have did this

On top of the page

```
$p->js()->_load('seteo_foco');
```

And then

seteo_foco.js

```
$(function(){
  $("select:first").focus();
})
```

But this does not work.

Anybody can help ?

Thanks

Comment: which ATK version do you use? In current 4.2 I can't find `do_getAssoc()` method of DSQL. This looks something from old-school ATK :) You can use simply `->select()` instead of `->do_getAssoc()` because all `do_*` methods are obsolete.

Answer (score 1):

Try TRUE like
`$this->js(true)->_load('seteo_foco');` to load js file.

But in your js code your selector is incorrect. You need to specify you unique field. I'd use something like `$form->getElement('field_name')->js(true)->focus();` on the page after the form has been initialized.

Comment: `$form->getElement('field_name')->js(true)->focus()` is nicer and better approach in this case because there is no need to load additional js file just to focus one field :)

Comment: This is 4.0.3 I know its old. I can do something like $p->js(true)->_selector('#field')->hide(); but this with focus() don't. Thanks for your help

Comment: And how about `$p->js(true)->_selector('#field')->focus()` ?